# UITableView with large number of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to make sample chat app.

As part of it I'd like to make sending of images. I store them outside of CoreData in Documents folder. I face the problem of slow scrolling of tableView, because some of images are extremely large (for ex user can send panorama image).

I've moved reading of files to background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:message.imageAddress];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    rightImageCell.messageImageView.image = image;
                    [rightImageCell.messageImageView setNeedsDisplay];
                });

            });
```

But it has no effect.

Here is screenshot from profiler during scroll:
[image]

Comment: Maybe when storing the images you should also store a thumbnail version which can be used in the tableview.

Comment: @Nick I will use this option for sure, if I won't find any other solution. I believe whatsapp stores additional image for previeww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the code you supplied,  I suspect that the image is larger than the UIImageView in the cell.   That is triggering all the resizing work on the main thread because that is where the image is set.

To prevent that, you should resize the image to the size of the image view in the background thread.  Then when you dispatch to the main thread, the only work needed is just replacing the image in the image view.

The WWDC 2012 video "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS" had great examples of this.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Answer (score 1):

[FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache) may be what you are needing. Note that this does not persists the images from web to use later, but it creates a memory image map with the resized images to display on screen.

> Fast Image Cache is an efficient, persistent, and—above all—fast way to store and retrieve 
>   images in your iOS application. Part of any good iOS application's
>   user experience is fast, smooth scrolling, and Fast Image Cache helps
>   make this easier.
>
> A significant burden on performance for graphics-rich applications
>   like Path is image loading. **The traditional method of loading
>   individual images from disk is just too slow, especially while scrolling.** Fast Image Cache was created specifically to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with CollectionViews that had really high resolution images.

The way I solved it was to pre-populate the images into an array and then simply using the index of the array to get the images. I also scaled them down to a thumbnail size before putting them into the array.

Since TableViews reuse cells, you dont want to use imageWithContentsOfFile:message in any method that is called when the TableView needs to reload its data (like when you scroll). 
You might want to use imageNamed instead, which would cache the image and avoid reloading it over and over when the table cells scroll on and off the screen.

Here is a good resource: http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. AFAIK imageNamed is used only for bundle images, so loaded images cannot be loaded with it.